# How to inject necessary objects into AspectJ aspects using Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, aop, guice, aspectj

Is there a way to use Guice and AspectJ for situation where i have an aspect which have to use some complex-to-instantiate service in its logic?

For example:

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {

  private final ComplexServiceMangedByGuice complexServiceMangedByGuice;

  @Inject
  public SomeAspect(ComplexServiceMangedByGuice complexServiceMangedByGuice){
    this.complexServiceMangedByGuice = complexServiceMangedByGuice;
  }

  @AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* *(..))", throwing = "e")
  public void afterThrowingException(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e){
    complexServiceMangedByGuice.doSomething(e);
  }
}
```

If i try having it like in the example (with aspect constructor), my aspect will not be called. If i try injecting field (without aspect constructor defined), aspect will be called but field `complexServiceMangedByGuice` won't be set. 
One solution i have found is to get instance in advice method body, so an aspect would look like this:

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {

private static ComplexServiceManagedByGuice complexServiceManagedByGuice;

  @AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* *(..))", throwing = "e")
  public void afterThrowingException(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e){
    if(complexServiceManagedByGuice == null){
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ModuleWithComplexService());
    complexServiceMangedByGuice = injector.getInstance(ComlexServiceManagedByGuice.class);
    }
    complexServiceMangedByGuice.doSomething(e);
  }
}
```

But that has some undesirable overhead.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire yes,  i wrote it in the question.:) If i try injecting field (without aspect constructor defined), aspect will be called but field complexServiceMangedByGuice won't be set.

Answer (score 6):

You can annotate fields of your aspect class like so:

```
@Inject
SomeDependency someDependency
```

Then ask Guice to inject dependencies into your aspect class by writing this in your Guice module's `configure()` method:

```
requestInjection(Aspects.aspectOf(SomeAspect.class));
```

The docs for `requestInjection` say:

> Upon successful creation, the Injector will inject instance fields and methods of the given object

Source: https://github.com/jponge/guice-aspectj-sample

Answer (score 1):

This is something I have wrestled with, and I don't think there is a good answer.

The two libraries basically work against each other: The AspectJ aspects are essentially static, and [Guice abhors making anything injectable be static](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AvoidStaticState).

I think your options are:

- Use [Guice AOP](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP) - Clean, but limited compared to AspectJ (can only weave injected classes)
- Put the injector into a static "global" reference so the aspect can access it. (Yuck.)
- Use some sort of thread-context (ultimately a thread-local) to communicate the injector to the aspect (Also yuck - though maybe less so)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what do you mean by 'AspectJ aspects are essentially static'?

Comment: While this answer makes some good points they are not solid as zAlbee answer shows there is a practical way to inject into Aspects via Guice.